After slicing the 2:1 picture, using canvas and CanvasTexture to draw it, overlap appeared in the stitching
After slicing the 2:1 picture, using canvas and CanvasTexture to draw it, I pasted it on a panorama ball, and there was overlap at the concatenation.
enter image description here
This is not a problem when I directly load the artwork with TextureLoader.load
enter image description here
